# Usage of the word "ordinance"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following paragraph is an excerpt from "Echopraxia" by Peter Watts:

> Twenty minutes later, a retinue of flukes and cestodes only
>   half-cataloged, something exploded in the distance.
>
> That’s what it
>   sounded like, anyway: the soft muffled whoompf of far-off *ordinance*.
>   Brüks rose from his work, panned the desert between spindly gnarled
>   trunks.

According to dictionaries *ordinance* is an *order* or *legalisation*. Is it a mistake and the author meaned *ordnance* as *weapons, ammunition* or is there some meaning of *ordinance* that is *something in the distance*?

Comment: It's a mistake, but it's impossible to say whose mistake it is. *Ordnance* is not a common word, and anybody along the publication trail might have misread or mistranscribed it as its historical ancestor.

Comment: *Ordnance* is in quite common usage here as the UK government agency responsible for the official, definitive topographic survey and mapping of Great Britain is named 'The Ordnance Survey' and hence most map bases are also referred to as 'the Ordnance Survey'. I'm not sure to what degree people realise the military roots and purposes of accurate national mapping.

Comment: _Ordnance_ is the least odd thing about that excerpt if you ask me. I’m much more baffled by the first sentence, though I suspect that may just be because I haven’t got the context. “A retinue of flukes and cestodes only half-cataloged” is perhaps the oddest parenthetical clause I have come across this year. I would also consider the entire first sentence borderline grammatical at best.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Consider that he was cataloging Trump's cabinet picks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ordnance](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ordnance) was once ordinance.

> ordnance (n.)
>
> "cannon, artillery," 1540s, a clipped form of ordinance (q.v.) which was attested from late 14c. in the sense of "military materials, provisions of war;" a sense now obsolete but which led to those of "engines for discharging missiles" **The shorter word was established in these distinct senses by 17c.** Ordnance survey (1833), official survey of Great Britain and Ireland, was undertaken by the government under the direction of the Master-General of the
> ranges and distances)

[Ordinance](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ordinance&allowed_in_frame=0)

> c. 1300, "an authoritative direction, decree, or command" (narrower or more transitory than a law), from Old French ordenance (Modern French ordonnance) or directly from Medieval Latin ordinantia, from Latin ordinantem (nominative ordinans), present participle of ordinare "put in order" (see ordain). **By early 14c. senses had emerged of "arrangement in ranks or rows" (especially in order of battle), also "warlike provisions, equipment" (a sense now in ordnance).**

Comment: I'm not sure the original sense is entirely obsolete. I served in the military (in Africa, but English-speaking) in the 1980s and to us ordinary soldiers 'ordnance' meant any kind of manufactured military equipment, not just actual weaponry.